# C# NumericUpDown failed validation - scroll buttons stop working

Tags: c#, winforms, button, scroll, numericupdown

So I have a situation that I cannot seem to figure out.  I have a `NumericUpDown` control that takes a `decimal` value with the `Increment` property set to 0.125.  When the user types in an invalid value, I cancel validation by setting `e.Cancel = true;` and a message is then displayed to let the user know it's invalid.  The issue is that when they exit the `MessageBox` and return to the form, the scroll buttons in the `NumericUpDown` no longer work.  Scrolling with the up/down arrows on the keyboard work just fine, but the buttons will not even depress.

I found a post on another forum where someone was having the same issue and apparently this is due to the `ValidationCancelled` property being set to `true` after validation fails ([link](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=46711) - see item #5 in his list of issues).  In the final post, he mentions finding the bug and using reflection to set the property to false again, but I can't seem to find where to put that code (the property is set after the `NumericUpDown_Validating` event completes).

Is there a function that will fire when validation ends?  I know `NumericUpDown_Validated` won't fire since I'm cancelling.  I feel like whatever I'm missing is sooo simple....

```
    private void NumericUpDown_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
            if (NumericUpDown.Value % 0.125m != 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Please enter a value in 1/8\" increments (0.125).  The value you entered is {0}.  Please use the up/down arrows on the right side of the text box for valid dimensions."
                    , NumericUpDown.Value), "Invalid Dimension", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                e.Cancel = true;

                //reset value to multiple of 0.125 so scroll increment will provide valid values
                NumericUpDown.Value = NumericUpDown.Value - (NumericUpDown.Value % 0.125m);
            }
    }
```

Here's the solution that was presented in the link from above:

> I think I have "solved" this, but I'm not terribly thrilled about the solution. I used a reflector as Shuggy suggested and found that the button clicks don't do anything if the internal ValidationCancelled flag is set to true. I'm not sure why this would be the desired behavior, since the user is still able to change the value using the arrow keys or a scroll wheel. So I'm using reflection to reset this flag to false....

Any advice?

**EDIT:** The issue is only occurring when the `Enter` key is set to be the `AcceptButton` for the form.  Clicking the `OKButton` or hitting the `Tab` key doesn't reproduce the issue, only using `Enter` to submit/validate the form.  Here's the code snippet from `System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl` where `ValidationCancelled` is set and which causes the scroll to stop working:

```
                if ((activeControl == this.activeControl) && (activeControl != null))
                {
                    CancelEventArgs ev = new CancelEventArgs {
                        Cancel = true
                    };
                    activeControl.NotifyValidationResult(unvalidatedControl, ev);
                    if (activeControl is ContainerControl)
                    {
                        ContainerControl control4 = activeControl as ContainerControl;
                        if (control4.focusedControl != null)
                        {
                            control4.focusedControl.ValidationCancelled = true;
                        }
                        control4.ResetActiveAndFocusedControlsRecursive();
                    }
                }
                this.SetActiveControlInternal(this.unvalidatedControl);
```

Comment: I know it's not any help, but I can't for the life of me reproduce this issue. Using your exact code gives the error message, resets back to the proper .125 increment and allows me to click the controls arrow buttons.

Comment: I am in agreement with Charles May… Creating a new winforms project, dropping a `NumericUpDown` control on the form, setting its `Increment` property to 0.125, setting the `DecimalPlaces` property to 3, adding the `Validating` event with the code supplied above and finally adding a `Button` control  used to leave focus from the numeric up and down control… I do NOT get the same issue as you describe above.

Comment: Example: If I change the NUD’s value to 0.333 then try to click the button, the `Validating` events dialog in the code pops up and display the error message, changes the value down to the nearest 0.125 value and the NUDs buttons still work as expected.

Comment: If you are changing the INVALID value to a rounded down VALID value with the line `NumericUpDown.Value = NumericUpDown.Value - (NumericUpDown.Value % 0.125m);`… I am wondering why you want to cancel the validation. Setting `e.Cancel` to `true` or `false` makes no difference since you are changing the users INVALID value with a VALID value upon leaving the `Validating` event. Are you sure there is not something else going on AFTER you leave the `Validating` event?

Comment: I'll have to double check a couple things...the original reason for cancelling validation was to prevent the form from closing if the user clicked the OKButton.  I'll double check exactly what's going on here....

Comment: VS Pro 2017 .NET 4.5 BTW

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere.  Hitting tab to force validation on the LoseFocus event works as expected and so does clicking the OK button; however, submitting the form by pressing "Enter" is what is causing my problem.....

Comment: Your last comment implies that there is another event (possibly a key event) wired up to the NUD since pressing “Enter” while the NUD has focus does nothing. It will not even fire the `Validating` event and the NUD will remain in focus after pressing the “Enter” key.

Comment: @JohnG If the form's AcceptButton is set to the OK button, it could start the fire works.

Comment: @LarsTech… I hope I got that right. Thank you for your insightful comment.

Comment: @JohnG From my scenario, pressing Enter will fire the NumBox's validating event.  Basically, I was disputing the comment above mine, where you say pressing the Enter key wouldn't have any repercussions.

Comment: @LarsTech… Hmmm I hope I am not missing something, however my test using the `NumericUpDown` as described above does NOT fire the `Validating` event when the “Enter” key is pressed. Granted if the “Enter” key is wired up to close the form or move focus to another control, then the `Validating` event gets fired. I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: @LarsTech - Bingo....it's the AcceptButton.  There aren't any key event overrides and the defaults weren't being hit either.  It's trying to submit the form and setting the CancelEventArg.Cancel property is preventing the form from closing

Comment: @JohnG, yes the OKButton is wired as the AcceptButton for the form.  It fires the `Validating` event and then, after `e.Cancel` is set to `true` and validation completes, execution moves to the `ContainerControl.cs` code in `System.Windows.Forms` namespace in the `ValidateThroughAncestor` function.  Line 1062 is where the `ValidationCancelled` property is set to `true`: